# When does an HTTP server start returning data?

Tags: http, networking

After a connection has been established between client and server, the client starts sending an HTTP request.  This consists of a line that looks something like `GET / HTTP/1.1` followed by several lines of headers.  My question is, how does a web server know when to start returning data?  Does the client somehow close its side of the connection to indicate it is done with the request and is ready to start receiving the response?  Does the server just know after the "\r\n\r\n" string at the end of the headers? Is it something else entirely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the HTTP 1.1 specification. The serve has to read the entire request before it can formulate and send the response. There are at least two ways it can know where the request ends:

1. `Content-length` header
2. Chunked transfer encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [HTTP 1.1 core specifications](http://httpwg.github.io/specs/).

> **19.4.6 Introduction of Transfer-Encoding**
>
> HTTP/1.1 introduces the Transfer-Encoding header field (section
>      14.41). Proxies/gateways MUST remove any transfer-coding prior to
>      forwarding a message via a MIME-compliant protocol.
>
> A process for decoding the "chunked" transfer-coding (section 3.6)
>      can be represented in pseudo-code as:
>
> ```
>    length := 0
>    read chunk-size, chunk-extension (if any) and CRLF
>    while (chunk-size > 0) {
>       read chunk-data and CRLF
>       append chunk-data to entity-body
>       length := length + chunk-size
>       read chunk-size and CRLF
>    }
>    read entity-header
>    while (entity-header not empty) {
>       append entity-header to existing header fields
>       read entity-header
>    }
>    Content-Length := length
>    Remove "chunked" from Transfer-Encoding
> ```